# How to load AJAX multiple times to change pages (page numbers) respectively?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have something like this:
(ignore the ugliness of the code).

```
<code><script type="text/javascript">
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4){
        document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}

function send(){
    xmlhttp.open("GET","search.php?term=" + "tom" + "&page=1", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</code>
```

Making the object, as soon as page loads and then I click the input button to trigger the "send()" method - It does not work :/

I have to make a page, where I could change pages dynamically with AJAX. I have 2 buttons 
"<kbd><<</kbd>" to go back by one page
"<kbd>>></kbd>" to go forth
So, when my (lets say) `index.php` loads, I want 2 pages (page-1 and page+1) to be loaded, so when I click on one of the buttons, it will display the page contents (without refreshing the page).

Can someone help me?
P.S. Sorry about my English.

Thank You! :)

EDIT: When I do 2 AJAX loads (to get curPage-1 and currentPage+1) How can I store the contents so I could access them later (lets say for.. alerting, lol).

---

nope, it does not work, even the most simple one:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>

function click() {
    $("body").load("search.php");
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Click Me!" onclick="click()"/>
</body>
</html>

<?php //search.php
    echo "ajax!?";
?>
```

So what am I missing here?

---

Trying to explain my problem here (again): I have a web page where there is a list of (lets say) 10 items. Everything works from a GET method (able to change parameters directly from URL; ..?page=4&term=Star%20Wars). There is a input box (for searching) and 'back' and 'forward' buttons (for going back and forth). Right now it works as follows: Searching for a book called "Star Wars". Ill be redirected to the same page and PHP kicks in(getting paramaters - $_GET['page/ term']). ..Then I have 2 beautiful variables: page=2 term="Star Wars" displaying the items of page 2.

..and when 'next page' button is pressed then AJAX will load the next page, page variable incremented (page=3); So I get the contents (entire HTML) from page 3 and then data is displayed, replacing the body element or whatever...

Now, that was just an introduction, the question is: How can I make 2 AJAX calls BEFORE I need to click the buttons(add 'onload' to body?). How can I then store the contents of 2 pages(contents of page 2 and page 4; when current page is 3) and 
when I really click the buttons I would not have to WAIT for the pages to load (though page never refreshes ) and I could get data IMMEDIALITY.

Pages load long (+3 seconds) because I'm using an external API to display the items.

Hope I made sense..

Sorry about weird-looking message(Everything looked better, before posting it, lol) and of course - my English grammar.

regards

EDIT:

nope, it does not work, even the most simple one:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>

function click() {
    $("body").load("search.php");
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Click Me!" onclick="click()"/>
</body>
</html>

<?php //search.php
    echo "ajax!?";
?>
```

So what am I missing here?

---

Trying to explain my problem here (again): I have a web page where there is a list of (lets say) 10 items. Everything works from a GET method (able to change parameters directly from URL; ..?page=4&term=Star%20Wars). There is a input box (for searching) and 'back' and 'forward' buttons (for going back and forth). Right now it works as follows: Searching for a book called "Star Wars". Ill be redirected to the same page and PHP kicks in(getting paramaters - $_GET['page/ term']). ..Then I have 2 beautiful variables: page=2 term="Star Wars" displaying the items of page 2.

..and when 'next page' button is pressed then AJAX will load the next page, page variable incremented (page=3); So I get the contents (entire HTML) from page 3 and then data is displayed, replacing the body element or whatever...

Now, that was just an introduction, the question is: How can I make 2 AJAX calls BEFORE I need to click the buttons(add 'onload' to body?). How can I then store the contents of 2 pages(contents of page 2 and page 4; when current page is 3) and 
when I really click the buttons I would not have to WAIT for the pages to load (though page never refreshes ) and I could get data IMMEDIALITY.

Pages load long (+3 seconds) because I'm using an external API to display the items.

Hope I made sense..

Sorry about weird-looking message(Everything looked better, before posting it, lol) and of course - my English grammar.

regards

Comment: so where is the problem, man? )

Comment: Should you be changing the value of the HTML tag - this is the top-level tag of the whole document.  Wouldn't it make more sense to have a DIV tag with particular ID within the document, and then use document.getElementById() to change its content.  Also, consider using jquery - it'll make this kind of thing much easier.

Comment: When index.php has loaded its contents (onload), then I want to load 2 pages ( with AJAX ) ; currentPage + 1 and currentPage - 1. So when I click the button "<<" or ">>" I Would get the content of the previous or next page respectively - without reloading.
How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a javascript framework, such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), to ease some of the ajax complexities.

Using jQuery you can do something like this:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
      function click() {
        $("body").load("search.php?term=" + "tom" + "&page=1");
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Click Me!" onclick="click()"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

And with **search.php**:

```
<?php
// search.php
echo "<b>This is loaded by ajax!</b>";
```

Hopefully this puts you on the right track.

Comment: jason, Thank You!

- I will test it out! :)